# principal solution of trigonometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have seen some books giving principal solution of trigonometric equation lie in the range of their corresponding Inverse trigonometric functions. For example:

The principal solution of $$\sin x=\frac{1}{2}$$ is $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

that is principal solution of $sinx=siny$ lie in range $[\frac{-\pi}{2} \:\: \frac{\pi}{2}]$

Some books gave that Principal solution of all Trigonometric functions always lie in $[0 \:\: 2\pi)$ 
so in above example there are two principal solutions are $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}$

i am confused which one we have to follow?

Comment: I think its confined to first quadrant

Comment: You follow whichever one your teacher tells you to follow. If you don't have a teacher, you follow whichever one you like, BUT be sure to inform your reader as to which one you are following.

Comment: Disagree with @ArchisWelankar. If sin$x<0$, then $x$ is not in the first quadrant.

Comment: Yes you are right @scott ill ask my professor about this as it was told by him.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have an equation in the form of,

$ \sin (x) = \sin (y) $

Then, the principal solution is

$ x = nπ+(-1)^ny \qquad n ∈ \mathbb{Z}$

Where, $y ∈ \bigg[- \dfrac{π}{2} , \dfrac{π}{2}\bigg]$

For example,

You have a equation,

$ \sin(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$

$ \implies \sin(x)= \sin \bigg( \dfrac{π}{6}\bigg) = \sin \bigg( \dfrac{5π}{6}\bigg)$ That is true but,

Principal solution is always,

$x= nπ+(-1)^n\dfrac{π}{6} \qquad n\in \mathbb{Z} $

Because $ \dfrac{π}{6} $ lies in $\bigg(- \dfrac{π}{2}, \dfrac{π}{2}\bigg)$

Hope your doubt is cleared.